# sort array starting from a predefined value

Tags: matlab, sorting

Is there a way to sort the elements of an array starting from a predefined values?

For example I want to transform: `V = [5 6 7 1 2]` in `V2 = [2 5 6 7 1]`.

In this case I wanted to start with the value 2

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  What defines the order of a sort that "starts with the value 2?"

Comment: @sfstewman sorry if I wasn't clear.
I want to sort with ascending order the vector V, but instead of starting with 1 as sort would do I want to start sorting from a certain value and then appending the smaller values at the end. In this case I want to start with 2 so 1 will go at the end of V2

Comment: Sorting requires a way to order elements.  It's not clear how you would order elements.  What do you do with elements less than 2?  If your array is `[ -1 -2 -1 0 0 1 1 2]`, what is the sorted order that you desire?

Comment: In what order will the unsorted elements be put into your sorted array? I get it that they will be put into the end of the array but in what order ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so (assuming `V` is a row vector):

```
value = 2
V2 = sort(V);
V2 = circshift(V2, [1, -find(V2 == value, 1) + 1]);
```

Explanation: first you need to sort `V`. Then you find the index of the first element equal to `value` with `find(V2 == value, 1)`. Finally, you have to 'rotate' the sorted vector by the correct amount to get `value` in the first position. Since `V` is a row-vector, you need to rotate along the second dimension, so you have to use `[1, ...]` as the second argument to circshift. Note that this only works if `value` is actually part of `V`.

Demonstration:

```
>> V = [5 6 7 1 2];
>> value = 2;
>> V2 = sort(V);
>> V2 = circshift(V2, [1, -find(V2 == value, 1) + 1])
V2 =
     2     5     6     7     1
```

and

```
>> V = [ -1 -2 -1 0 0 1 1 2];
>> value = 2;
>> V2 = sort(V);
>> V2 = circshift(V2, [1, -find(V2 == value, 1) + 1])
V2 =
     2    -2    -1    -1     0     0     1     1
```

Comment: I believe the need for `value` to be a part of `V` can be eliminated like this: `V2 = circshift(V2, [1, -find(V2 >= value, 1) + 1])`. This should work since `V2` is already sorted.

Comment: Yes, that would already be better, but I guess it still fails when `value > max(V)`.

Comment: I don't know what OP will use this for, but this should work for positive numbers: `V2 = circshift(V2, [1, -find(V2 >= (value * (value <= max(V2)), 1) + 1])`